# Django Template: Displaying variable with optional content

Tags: django, django-templates

The code below is what I do when I have content with before to display:

```
{% if content %}
    <p> The variable contains: {{ content }}</p>        
{% endif %}
```

Isn't there a shortcuts that will help so that I don't check the value of `content` each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some surrounding html code then `{% if %}` tag is the only solution.

But if you want to output some content in case if variable is empty then there are two useful filters:

```
{{ content|default:"no content" }}
{{ content|yesno:"content is True, content is False, content is None" }}
```